# Исправить опечатку пустых меток/тегов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, описание-метки

> Для этой метки до сих пор нет описания.
>
> Описание помогает новичкам глубже понять тематику метки, содержит
>   обзор темы, которую представляет метка, а также инструкции по её
>   использованию.
>
> Все **зарегис*ти*рованные** пользователи могут предлагать новые описания
>   меток.
>
> (Обратите внимание: если у вас меньше 20000 баллов репутации, то перед
>   публикацией ваши изменения в описании метки должны будут пройти
>   проверку).

- пропущена ***Р*** (зарегист***р***ированные)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходная англоязычная строка в текущем состоянии Transifex была вовсе не переведена. Видимо, перевод с опечаткой остался от прежних версий базы и не слетел полностью в англоязычную по какой-то причине. Таким образом строку нельзя было найти по русскому переводу. Пришлось искать по оригиналу:

> All registered users may propose new tag wikis.

[Строка была найдена](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/144191812?q=key%3Af93dbbc153870d5e2830ce69bdc51eb5) и переведена с учётом исправления очепятки.

> Все зарегистрированные пользователи могут предлагать новые описания меток.

Будет на сайте после обновления базы и пересборки движка.